# How to know how long I have launched this machine

Tags: windows-10, powershell

If I'm *Linux*, I can use `uptime` to get such information,like this

[image]

*PowerShell* can do this?

Comment: See if my answer [Why is the system uptime too long despite shutdown?](//superuser.com/a/954149) works for Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a different take on this one, using only PowerShell.
Using [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/12/28/powertip-get-time-difference-between-dates-with-powershell/) as a foundation:

```
New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem).LastBootUpTime -End (Get-Date)
```

This [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/27/powertip-get-the-last-boot-time-with-powershell/) also shows how you can use Get-WMIObject if you need to.

This one gets a little long.....

```
New-TimeSpan -Start ((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | `
Select-Object @{Name='LastBootUptime';Expression={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}).lastbootuptime) -End (Get-Date)
```

From there you can format the object to not have Milliseconds etc.

For example:

```
New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem).LastBootUpTime -End (Get-Date) | `
Select-Object Days,Hours
```

Thanks, Tim.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it with Windows command:

```
systeminfo|find "Time:"
```

Comment: It depends of the language of your system...

Answer (score 1):

Type `net statistics workstation` in Powershell to view how long machine has been turned on.
It will show the system uptime and since how long the machine has been turned on. Also you can find one more method here- http://www.penguincoders.net/2015/12/find-computer-uptime-in-windows-operating-system.html